# How to resolve "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" while coloring specific cells of an Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I want to color some particular cells of an Excel sheet in C#. I am using this code:

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells[2, 1]).Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbDarkRed;
```

But it's throwing an exception:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it will solve your problem

```
 ((Range)worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```